Is there any way to setup a duplicate rule the for Work Order Object?
I'm currently trying to enforce a duplicate rule for the work order object but for some reason it's not available as an option on either the matching rule or duplicate rule settings.

Unfortunately not all objects are available for the duplicate rules feature, and the only way to find out is to try it.
